# Setup express js to drop requests by default

Tags: node.js, express

I tried tinkering with node servers, and here is a server that I tried:

```js
const http = require("http");

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
}).listen(8080);
```

This server does nothing, besides telling me that someone tried to connect. I can see that if I try to connect via browser or `curl -X GET localhost:8080`, the server logs the connection, while the browser and curl just hangs.

Now I move to express, using its hello world:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This does send the expected response on the expected route and method. However, now if I decide to access something I'm not handling, for example `GET localhost:8080/ABC` or `POST localhost:8080`, I get a HTML page:

```sh
$ curl -X GET localhost:8080/ABC
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /ABC</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I configure express to not respond to any request by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default feature of Express if any route does not available in backend it will throw 404 with a requested query if query

```
$ curl -X GET localhost:8080/ABC
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /ABC</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

If you  don't Want to not respond to any requests other than your routes use This

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello");
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("Came Here)
});
```

Set this middleware At bottom of the routes so anyone Requested routes that are not available will console.log("Came here") And it will load forever But this is BAD practice and weak user experience I would recommend You to send a Static 404 Page instead of not replying

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello");
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).render("404"); //using template If you want it simple Than //res.send(`<html><body>404 page does not exist</body></html>`)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an error handler.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-9hnac1?file=index.js

```
//error handler
app.use((err, req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
});
```